# Firefox extensions: permissions that let grabbing username/password

Tags: firefox, permissions, passwords, firefox-extensions

What specific permissions would allow a Firefox extension to grab my username and password, either if I enter them by hand or retrieved from the password manager?
(It would be great to have links to official/reputable documentation for this).

This is the first step in understanding how can I avoid user/pass leaks.
See [Firefox extensions: avoiding possible username/password leaks](https://superuser.com/questions/1540676/firefox-extensions-avoiding-possible-username-password-leaks?noredirect=1#comment2340148_1540676)

PS: There is no need to clarify that one should install only trusted extensions. The question only points to the technical aspect.

Answer (score 0):

#### What permissions allow a Firefox extension to grab my username and password?

> **Access your data for all websites**
>
> The extension can read the content of any web page you visit as well
>   as data you enter into those web pages, such as usernames and
>   passwords.
>
> Extensions requesting this permission might:
>
> - Read product and price information from a page to help find you the best price on items you're shopping for
> - **Offer a password manager that reads and writes details of your username and password**
>
> **Access your data for sites in the “named” domain**
>
> The extension could read the content of web pages you visit in the
>   specified domain, as well as data you enter into those web pages, such
>   as **usernames and passwords**.
>
> **Access your data in # other domains**
>
> Used in conjunction with the named domain message (above) when the
>   extension is requesting access to five or more domains; the first
>   three are listed and the other domain requests counted.
>
> **Access your data for “named site”**
>
> The extension could read the content of any web pages you visit at the
>   specified website, as well as any data you enter into those web pages,
>   such as **usernames and passwords**.
>
> **Access your data on # other sites**
>
> Used in conjunction with the named website message (above) when the
>   extension is requesting access to five or more websites—the first
>   three are listed and the other website requests counted.
>
> **Exchange messages with programs other than Firefox**
>
> The extension could send messages to and receive them from a
>   complementary native app on your computer.
>
> The complementary app needs to be installed on your computer
>   independently of the extension. This usually happens in one of two
>   ways:
>
> - The extension will provide a guide to the steps you should follow to install the app
> - You would have installed an app that then suggests you install an extension in Firefox
>
> ...
>
> Extensions requesting this permission might:
>
> - Use a complementary app to communicate with hardware attached to your computer
> - **Store usernames and passwords using a secure method not available to a browser**

Source [Permission request messages for Firefox extensions | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/permission-request-messages-firefox-extensions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=permission-request-messages-explained)

Comment: In trying to interpret what is written, it seems to me that for all permissions except the last, I would be safe using my proposal of https://superuser.com/questions/1540676/firefox-extensions-avoiding-possible-username-password-leaks?noredirect=1#comment2340148_1540676 ... would you think so?