# Firefox extensions: avoiding possible username/password leaks

Tags: firefox, passwords, firefox-extensions

I understand a FF extension cannot read info stored in the password manager but, with suitable permission/s (see [Firefox extensions: permissions that let grabbing username/password](https://superuser.com/questions/1540674/firefox-extensions-permissions-that-let-grabbing-username-password)) it can read a user/pass for a site whenever they are used in a webpage, 
either if I enter them by hand or retrieved from the password manager.

I conceive a possible method to avoid any risk of the extension reading such information.

I would: 1) disable the extension, 2) open a tab for the site, 3) enter the info, 4) start browsing the site (but not using the user/pass again), 5) enable the extension.

Is this procedure 100% safe? Are there any mechanisms for the extension to grab the user/pass while I am navigating the site?

PS: There is no need to clarify that one should install only trusted extensions. The question only points to the technical aspect.

Comment: If the extension is not allowed in privacy mode (extension does not has the "white mask on purple background" icon in the extension list) you could also use a privacy tab.

Comment: I wouldn’t count on the fact a disabled extension doesn’t use some or all of it’s allowed permissions.  I would simply use privacy mode, and explicitly indicate, the extension has no permissions within privacy mode.

Comment: @Robert - This is an option. But then I would not be able to take advantage of the extension features (e.g., a mass downloader) during subsequent navigation in the site, I guess.

Comment: @Ramhound - My question points precisely to that. I wonder whether FF, by design, becomes "impermeable" to the extension once it is disabled. Otherwise, what would "disabled" mean?

Comment: I don’t trust extensions enough not to have allowed permissions while being disabled.  I do trust privacy mode, to prevent an extension, from being enabled and blocking permissions on an extension.